# Android web apps shockingly doesn't need additional drag to scroll scripts?

Tags: javascript, android, html, draggable, drag

Fairly recently I've been trying to make my own web based android app and have been going crazy trying to find a working drag to scroll JavaScript but surprise, surprise, turns out I didn't need it. Because as long as the overflow parameters are not set to hidden, I could drag-scroll like crazy.

I'm very new to this web to app thing so can anyone explain why and how this works? Because I can't seem to find the right key words to find a documentation for it.

Comment: I might be missing something but how else would you scroll? You wouldnt have to implement scrolling just as you dont have to implement clicking. That is very basic stuff that every app needs.

Comment: huh, kind of makes sense. I don't really do programming a lot and just thought right off the bat that you _absolutely_ have to have a drag scroll script to move stuff when on android. Lol i'm not really on to the whole mobile programming thing. Didn't even care about that stuff until fairly recently. I didn't ask a lot of questions when I was a kid XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a change on Android in the **WebKit** browser that was started in this issue:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78664

The property was added in [this](https://github.com/adobe/webkit/commit/2ec3eb5aaaa5a2b493774ab4ce1725f47f7fd6c3) revision.

Looking at the code you can see it's **default value** is `touch` on touch-enabled devices.